# In monotouch how to make status bar text color to white for ios7?

Tags: xamarin.ios, ios7

For some screens status bar text color is white but for some screens it is black,So how to change it to white for all for ios7.
I had use `PreferedStatusBarStyle()` method but it is not executing.

Answer (score 1):

Just to be sure, `PreferedStatusBarStyle()` is not a method you call, but a method you have to override.

```cs
public partial class MyViewController : UIViewController
{
    public override UIStatusBarStyle PreferredStatusBarStyle ()
    {
        return UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent;
    }
}
```

Now, this only works for top-level view controllers (or the like, as a VC pushed in a `UINavigationController`). If you want a sub view controller to drive the status bar, override `ChildViewControllerForStatusBarStyle`

```cs
public partial class TopLevelViewController : UIViewController
{
    public override UIViewController ChildViewControllerForStatusBarStyle ()
    {
        return myNestedViewController.
    }
}
```

To be exhaustive, if the BarStyle has changed, make sure you let that fact known by calling `SetNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate ()`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: ,I tried this code already but its not executing(debugger is not going to that point).For some screens it is showing status bar textcolor white but for some screens it is showing color as black.